# where to put onclick listener for checboxes in recyclerview

Tags: android

I have gotten up to this far:

I have created a boolean variable in my "numbers" object class with a getter and setter. In my bindNumbers method near the bottom of my adapter, i set the checked state of my checkbox. I know that im supposed to now use a on click listener however i dont know how to accomplish this. Can someone give me a beginner friendly explanation on what to do now? All the other answers on the forums are much more advanced and arent helping me.

```
public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<numbers> mNumbers = Collections.emptyList();

public myAdapter (List<numbers> numbers) {
    mNumbers = numbers;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v  = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_slot, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.bindNumbers(mNumbers.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mNumbers.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView numberText;
    EditText checklistText;
    Button deleteButton;
    CheckBox checkDisBox;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        numberText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
        checklistText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        deleteButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        checkDisBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void bindNumbers(numbers numbers) {
        numberText.setText(numbers.getInt() + "");
        checkDisBox.setChecked(numbers.isChecked());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mNumbers.remove(getAdapterPosition());
        notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually add Listeners in the `onBindViewHolder()` method, i.e.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.bindNumbers(mNumbers.get(position));
    holder.checkDisBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener({
        ...
    }));
}
```

edit:

Short help for implementation: In your adapter, add:

```
public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<numbers> mNumbers = Collections.emptyList();
private SparseBooleanArray mCheckedItems;

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.bindNumbers(mNumbers.get(position));
    boolean checked = mCheckedItems.get(position), false;
    holder.checkDisBox.setChecked(checked);
    holder.checkDisBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener({
        mCheckedItems.put(position, !checked);
    }));
}
```

Comment: what code should i put inside the click listener? because of the viewholder pattern, my checkboxes are being all weird

Comment: I don't know, that depends on what you want to do when your checkbox is clicked

Comment: when i click the checkbox, i just want it to be checked. When i click it again i want it to be unchecked. so essentially i want nothing to happen other than the default. but the problem is we are reusing views in a recyclerview so when i check a box and scroll down, a random box will be checked because the view is being reused. i am looking for a solution to fix this. the other answers on the forums havent been much help as i dont need anything advanced and just something beginner

Comment: Take a parameter to hold save the information, which elements are checked, i.e. a SparseBooleanArray, then make a check in the `onBindViewHolder()` method if the current item is checked, and call `holder.checkDisBox.setChecked()` according to the result and add the item to the parameter in the `onClick()` of the checkbox

Comment: can you show me with an example? i didnt understand how to do what you wrote